# I am trying to add firebase email varification link varification to my app but getting error "can not read email propperty of null"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I am trying to add firebase email verification link verification to my app but getting an error `cannot read email property of null`

I tried to follow the firebase docs for the web but not able to find the complete solution exactly where and how to implement it

```
 var actionCodeSettings = {
  url: 'campatron.com' + firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  // When multiple custom dynamic link domains are defined, specify which
  // one to use.
  dynamicLinkDomain: "example.page.link"
};
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings)
  .then(function() {
    // Verification email sent.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred. Inspect error.code.
  });
```

Comment: here is code snipt for code review : https://gist.github.com/reactwo/bce364a76dc1c33f39abb48e2ca11be3

Answer (score 0):

The currentUser property is not yet initialized, meaning that your user is not yet logged in when you reach this code. Where is this piece of code called in your app?

Comment: here is the code snipt https://gist.github.com/reactwo/bce364a76dc1c33f39abb48e2ca11be3

Comment: Whenever this scripts gets imported you make this call 
var actionCodeSettings = {
  url: 'campatron.com' + firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  // When multiple custom dynamic link domains are defined, specify which
  // one to use.
  dynamicLinkDomain: "example.page.link"
};
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings)

Meaning that when you import your file you directly try to get the user email, try to put that in a function and call it when necessary

Comment: Thanks, Milenko putting this code inside a function worked for me :)